# SQLite : How to select only 2 groups?

Tags: jquery, sql, database, sqlite

My data looks like below after running Select all

```
SELECT *
FROM query_23
GROUP BY week,report_date order by week;
```

Results:

[image]

As you can see in the above image the table consists three rows for week = 28/08/17 (It can contain many rows for the same week). In the right, you can find that various reported weeks and Target (i.e 目標)

I want to list only two rows- 1st contains target and 2nd contain latest reported date. For ex- in the above case I want data as follows:

```
28/08/17    12,098,469  2017/10/25報告
28/08/17    25,000,000  目標
```

i.e 2017/10/25 is latest as compared to 2017/10/16報告, so wanna include that plus one target row which is always there for the same week.

i tried various things but didn't work. Thanks.

visualization of current data looks below:
[image]

Comment: I can't read your data, and `28/08/17` is not an ISO compliant date format, and almost certainly will cause massive problems in a SQLite database.  _Always_ store your dates in a proper ISO format with SQLite.

Comment: Sry Actually Its not stored in the database. Its stored in the google spreadsheet. and I am using redash to manipulate data after from spreadsheet.

Comment: Please edit your question and make the data more clear.  I really can't read anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various queries it worked with the following query.

```
SELECT week,
   report_date,
   write_revenue
FROM query_23
GROUP BY week
UNION ALL
SELECT week,
   report_date,
   write_revenue 
FROM query_23
WHERE report_date = '目標'
ORDER BY week;
```

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It is never a good idea to combine different data types in one column (date and funny little pictures).
You would have to find a way (by that I mean a combination of SQL functions) to extract the date part to be able to compare them.
That said, you could perhaps get on your way with something like:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM query_23 a
LEFT JOIN query_23 b
ON b.report_date > a.report_date AND b.report_date != 'target'
WHERE a.report_date = 'target' OR b.report_date IS NULL 
GROUP BY a.week, a.report_date 
ORDER BY a.week
```

Of course you would have to replace `'target'` with some funny little pictures.